# How to make "\mid" well-lengthened as in this textbook?

Tags: vertical-spacing

I'm reading a textbook containing the following symbol

[image]

The `\mid` is well-lengthened. I tried `\,\middle\vert\,` but to no avail.

[image]

Could you elaborate on how to reproduce it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{E}\left\{\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(Y_i-m\left(X_i\right)\right) I_{\left\{X_i \in A_n(x)\right\}}}{n \mu_n\left(A_n(x)\right)}\right)^2 \,\middle\vert\, X_1, \ldots, X_n\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: note that `\mid` is something completely different. Here the author manually scaled the vertical bar. so something like `\Bigm\vert` might be what you are after. (remember the are four levels of manual scaling: `\big\Big\bigg\Bigg` each has `-l`, `-r` and `-m` variants. For example scaling `()`  ought ro be done using the l/r variants `\bigl(...\bigr)`. The `-m` variant adds a bit of extra spacing.

Comment: Additionally note that your equation only needs two sets of `\left...\right`, the rest does not contribute anything other than making your code harder to read.

Comment: @daleif Ah it's a side effect of using [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/)...

Comment: These generators often give suboptimal results.

Comment: See also the `\Set` macro example in the `mathtools` manual. IMO the `|` in the image is a bit small. I would use a size that match the `{}`, chances are that the author did not know how to do that.

Comment: @daleif Thank you so much for your help! The command `\Bigm\vert` does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show three versions; one is the textbook's, one is with a similarly reduced height middle bar but with a couple of fixes. The last one is a different possibility (I guess that the textbook's typesetter didn't know about `\middle`).

In any case, you should avoid too many `\left` and `\right`. Compare your version with them and the picture from the textbook.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Ex}{\mathbf{E}}% expectation

\begin{document}

The textbook version
\[
\Ex\left\{
  \biggl(
    \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-m(X_i)) I_{\{X_i \in A_n(x)\}}}
         {n \mu_n(A_n(x))}
  \biggr)^{2} 
  \,\Big|\, X_1, \ldots, X_n
\right\}
\]

A better one
\[
\Ex\biggl\{
  \biggl(
    \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-m(X_i)) I_{\{X_i \in A_n(x)\}}}
         {n \mu_n(A_n(x))}
  \biggr)^{\!2} 
  \Bigm| X_1, \ldots, X_n
\biggr\}
\]

Another possibility
\[
\Ex\left\{
  \biggl(
    \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-m(X_i)) I_{\{X_i \in A_n(x)\}}}
         {n \mu_n(A_n(x))}
  \biggr)^{\!2} 
  \;\middle|\; X_1, \ldots, X_n
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some points to notice. The exponent in the textbook seems to hang from nowhere; adding `\!` places it nearer the parenthesis. Also `\,` space around the bar is too small and `\;` instead adds the standard spacing around relation symbols.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can manually scale the `|` using `\vert` plus one of `\bigm`,...,`\Biggm`.